# Looking for a specialized launch bar for WinXP/7

Tags: windows, title-bar

Looking for a launchbar that has the following capabilities:

1. Icons only.
2. Can be free-floating OR pinned to a specific window's title bar.
3. In pinned mode, it has to smartly handle fitting between the title bar icons on the left and right. BONUS points for allowing title bar caption to remain visible.
4. Applications can be dropped on the bar to add them.
5. Data files can be dropped ON existing icons to launch the app with the designated data file.
6. Each bar starts with a drop down menu icon that will allow for editing settings, organize order of existing icons, etc.

An example of something that fulfills all but the pinning aspect would be something like RocketDock. But what I'm looking for is something akin to adding a hotkey bar to an application that doesn't have it already.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can't remember anything like this. At least not for all the features. Is really RocketDock close? The size looks big to me to fit next to the titlebar, if it was possible.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Rocketdock](http://www.rocketdock.com)...

Answer (score 0):

RocketDock can actually get down to using 16x16 pixel icons, which puts it in the ballpark of fitting onto a titlebar. But it can't be pinned to a window. At least I think it can't. Been awhile. When I ran it, I used 40 pixel size, but I distinctly remember trying it at the smallest size and it would have fit, or come within a pixel or two of fitting. The behaviour is very much what I want, except for the pinning issue. Heck, I'd even go for attaching the solution to the edge of the top window border, if being actually ON the titlebar is impossible.